# Keypress in textbox inside datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to calculate new value upon keypress in a textbox inside a datatable. However, the textbox inside the datatable is not triggering upon keypress.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '#table1 tr', function() {
  rndex = this;
  jindex = this.rowIndex;
});

var dtable = $('#table1').DataTable();
var origval = $('#table1 tr:eq(' + parseInt(rndex) + ') >td:eq(' + 1 + ')').html();
var $textvalue = $(jindex).find(".txtBox");
var newval; 

$textvalue.on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
  }
}).on('keyup change', function(e) {
  newval = parseFloat(origval) + this.value;
  alert(origval);
});
```

[image: Output]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The contents of a DataTable are dynamically generated, so you need to use a delegated event handler. See the duplicate question for more information